# Related to GStreamer in visual studio 2008

Tags: qt, cmake, gstreamer

I have installed cmake 2.8.1, QT 4.8.4 in 64bit win commercial, and visual studio 2008 c++. After configuring and generating in cmake, while trying to run the program in visual studio i get the following errors:

- cannot open include file: gst.h
- cannot open include file: gst/gst.h
- no such file or directory

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: -1 You didn't attach the most important thing here - a build scripts (CMakeFiles.txt or whatever you used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the include directory of GStreamer to your project - use the `include_directories()` 
 command in the corresponding CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Check in the project settings if the path to the include directory is correctly set. Just to make sure that the path can be found add also the absolute path.